# F# types or System types with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, f#

While building a F# ASP.NET MVC 4 app with the C#/F# template from the VisualStudio gallery, a doubt assaulted me. I have the following model class:

```
namespace MyApp.Models

open System
open System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
open System.Collections.Generic

type Product() = 
    [<Key>] member val Id = Guid.NewGuid() with get, set
    [<Required>] member val Name = "" with get, set
    member val Iban = "" with get, set
    member val Categories = new List<ProductCategory>() with get, set
```

As F# has its own types, in cases like the last one, should we use an F# equivalent (an F# list, a sequence...) or should we use System types? If so, what would be the reasoning?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, I'd go by what language(s) is(are) consuming your models. If it's F# all the way down, go for it. If it's mixed you'll need to be more judicious. As an aside, `Option<>` and `List<>` play pretty well with C# (though I find I need type aliases to "clean up" some of the code). Also an F# sequence is just an `IEnumerable<>`, so no worries there. Also, there's nothing wrong with using arrays and `ResizeArray<>` (aka `System.Collections.Generic.List<>`) in F# -- you just have to be mindful of state mutation.

Comment: One detail I didn't take into account is the fact that I'm using Entity Framework. I'll investigate that bit further but I think the safest option is to stay with System types anyway, and just play with F# types inside controllers, which are isolated bits of pure F# code. Thanks for your comment, I think I needed someone to put it that clear ;). Cheers!